# Different result for same value in sigmoid function [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, math, sigmoid

I am trying to find out the result of the sigmoid function. When I tried to compute it without loop. I did not get the expected result. On the other hand, using for loop getting an actual result.
The question is, Why I am getting different results?

```
%This is a hypothesis of AND operation
x1 = randi([0,1],[1,4]);
x2 = randi([0,1],[1,4]);
features = [x1;x2]';
theta = [-30 20 20];
x = [ones(length(features),1) features]
z = x * theta';
pred = zeros(length(z),1);
pred = 1 / (1 + exp(-z))
y1 = (pred >= 0.5)
fprintf('Using loop\n')
for i= 1:length(z)
    pred(i) = 1 / (1 + exp(-z(i)));
end
pred
y1 = (pred >= 0.5)
```

**Output:**

```
x =

     1     1     1
     1     0     1
     1     0     0
     1     0     1


pred =

   1.0e-13 *

         0         0    0.9358         0


y1 =

   0   0   0   0

Using loop

pred =
    1.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000


y1 =

   1   0   0   0
```

Comment: Try `pred = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-z))`

Comment: Warren is correct, as to the WHY, it's because `/` is a [matrix division](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html) and `./` is an elementwise [right array division](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html)

Comment: Yeah! it's working. Thank you so much